# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync sometimes crashes with ServerException: 'Unexpected end of network stream reading request line.'

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-oauth

The code (.NET Core 2.0 console app)

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = yourAppClientID,
        ClientSecret = yourAppClientSecret,
    },
     scopes,
     "user",
     CancellationToken.None);
```

sometimes hangs for a while and then, in 20 seconds or so, crashes with Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.LimitedLocalhostHttpServer.ServerException: 'Unexpected end of network stream reading request line.'

This happens in about 30-50% cases. I just run the app again and again. Sometimes it crashes, sometimes it works.

I also found that it seems to be something to do with the amount of data the method has to deal with. I currently has this in scopes:

{"https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", ""https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" }

It never times out if I'm requesting just this:

{"https://mail.google.com/" }

Also, it does not hang with another set of ClientId/Secret which are shorter.

This ClientID is quite long and may cause the issue (or may not, you never know):
XXXXXXXXXXXXX-irs73ni0v0kvqpibnop20uai3kar8geu.apps.googleusercontent.com

While this one is perfectly fine (even if all the scopes are requested):
XXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com

Looks like if may hang/crash if the payload exceeds certain limit or something like that.

Google.Apis.Auth I'm using is of the latest version 1.40.0.

Is there anything I can do to overcome this?